# Silex double form

Tags: forms, silex

I'm currently using Silex2 FormFactory to build a form and I stumbled on a problem.

I have a login page (login.twig), asking for email and a password. This form includes the validation. But I want to have this login form always in my header too (on my layout.twig ). I created the form and linked the action to the location of the login page. I had to manualy write the correct id and name of each input element, and I copied the generated token of the login.twig inside the form. But I doubt this is the correct way to do it?

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-right" action="{{ path('auth.login') }}" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">{# disables HTML5 formchecking #}
    <input class="span2" type="text" id="loginform_email" name="loginform[email]" placeholder="Email">
    <input class="span2" type="password" id="loginform_password" name="loginform[password]" placeholder="Password">
    <input id="loginform__token" type="hidden" value="9eb2a291d32d114987aee1548da878201dd79a7b" name="loginform[_token]">
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    <a href="{{ path('auth.register') }}">register here</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as they are unique instances of the same form, and referenced differently it should be fine.

But I would suggest for usability reasons to simply hide the login form from the header on the login page. You can determine the name of your route and set it as a global variable perhaps:

```
$app->before(function (Request $request) {
    $app['twig']->addGlobal('currentRoute', $request->get('_route'));
});
```

Then in your template:

```
{% if currentRoute != 'auth.login') %}
  // output your form here
{% endif %}
```